# UTF8 encoded strings not shown correctly in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, html, character-encoding

So I have programmed a crawler to scrape information and data from a website with charset utf8. But when I tried to store the contents into MySQL, some special characters, such as Spanish letters), did not show correctly in MySQL.

Here is what I have done:

1. Put `header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8")` in PHP
2. Set all charset in MySQL into `utf8-unicode-ci`
3. Have `$conn->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'")` this upon connection
4. Double checked that the html I parsed was encoded in utf-8

So what are some potentially problems here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you coded your crawler using functions which are not supposed to manage multi-byte characters.
For example strlen instead of mb_strlen.

Try putting:

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
```

as first line of your php coce, and then check if you have to convert some functions in their respective mb version.
Have a look at [multibyte string reference](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php)

As a last chance you may play with [iconv function](http://php.net/manual/it/function.iconv.php) just before inserting the string into mysql.
Something as:

```
$utf8_string = iconv(iconv_get_encoding($string), "UTF-8", $string);
```

should do the trick

Comment: @DanielZuo happy to give something back to the net :)

Answer (score 1):

Start by checking if the data is stored wrong in the database, in which case the problem is with your crawler. Otherwise the problem is in your presentation.

To test this, I would suggest that you use a dedicated mysql client (Such as the command line client) to inspect data.

Comment: Hi troelskn, my crawler used cURL to extract data and parse it with PHP DOM. The data storage is also very straightforward.

Comment: @DanielZuo The advice troelskn has given you is very good. It doesn't really matter how simple is your solution, it's important to see if the data is stored correctly or not to determine where the issue could be.

Answer (score 0):

I remember pulling my hair out in dealing with UTF8 issues until I started adding this to my header:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8');
```